# check in blade if exists variable in @include

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-7

I´m developping a system with laravel 7.4 and i need check if one variable that i´m sending from my controller exists in my blade. If exists, include it:

I have this code in my controller:

```
public function index()
    {
        //Store Image
        $newsItem = User::find(Auth::user()->id);

        if($newsItem->hasMedia('userPhoto')){
            $profilePhoto = $newsItem->getMedia('userPhoto')[0]->file_name;
            $idPhoto = $newsItem->getMedia('userPhoto')[0]->id;

            return view('home')->with('idPhoto', $idPhoto)
                               ->with('profilePhoto', $profilePhoto);

        }else if($newsItem->hasMedia('logoSystem')){
            $logoSystem = $newsItem->getMedia('logoSystem')[0]->file_name;
            $idPhotoLogo = $newsItem->getMedia('logoSystem')[0]->id;

            return view('home')->with('idPhotoLogo', $idPhotoLogo)
                               ->with('logoSystem', $logoSystem);
        }else{
            return view('home');
        }
        
        if($newsItem->getMedia('userPhoto') && $newsItem->getMedia('logoSystem')){
            return view('home')->with('idPhoto', $idPhoto)
                                ->with('profilePhoto', $profilePhoto)
                                ->with('idPhotoLogo', $idPhotoLogo)
                                ->with('logoSystem', $logoSystem);
        }
        
    }
```

this return `profile image` or `system image` but it´s possible that this images don´t exists and i need check before, because i have error in my system and i can´t show my view.

Whit this code in my view after, i created a image with this route:

```
{{-- asset('storage/'.$idPhoto."/".$profilePhoto) --}}
```

But previously i need send this variable ton my view `head` and after to my sidebar.

i´m traying to do this:

**home.blade.php**

```
@include('layouts.head', (isset([$idPhoto])) ? ["idPhoto" => $idPhoto, "idPhotoLogo" => $idPhotoLogo]  : '')
```

**head.blade.php**

```
@include('layouts.sidebar', ["idPhoto", $idPhoto, "idPhotoLogo" => $idPhotoLogo])
```

and in my sidebar created my image:

```
<img src="{{-- asset('storage/'.$idPhoto."/".$profilePhoto) --}}" alt="Logo" class="brand-image">
```

**UPDATED**

now i have this error:

in my **head.blade.php** i have this:

```
@if(isset([$idPhoto])
              @include('layouts.sidebar', ["idPhoto", $idPhoto, "idPhotoLogo" => $idPhotoLogo])
            @else
              @include('layouts.sidebar')
            @endif
```

in my **home.blade.php** i have this

```
@if(isset([$idPhoto])
    @include('layouts.head',["idPhoto" => $idPhoto, "idPhotoLogo" => $idPhotoLogo])
@else
    @include('layouts.head')
@endif
```

this return:

```
syntax error, unexpected token ":", expecting "(" (View: C:\wamp64\www\clinicaCampoy\resources\views\home.blade.php)
```

i need to do, that if table media is empty, load image for deafult, but if table media have logo or image system, load this images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use  if condition

```
@if(isset($idPhoto))
    @include('layouts.head',["idPhoto" => $idPhoto, "idPhotoLogo" => $idPhotoLogo])
    
@endif
```

Comment: thanks for your response, but return this: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead)

Comment: @scorpions78.updated with two options.let me which one work well for you

Comment: i edited my question with my actual problem with your code

Comment: if i use your first code i have this: Undefined variable $idPhoto (View:

Comment: update if condition .@if(isset([$idPhoto]))

Comment: i updated my question with my actual error

Comment: @scorpions78 .in if condition you have missed )  .@if(isset([$idPhoto]) so it should be @if(isset([$idPhoto]))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234184/discussion-between-john-lobo-and-scorpions78).

Comment: yes i resolve it. But condition it´s not correct... return this: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead)